# Solr and product SKUs

Tags: solr

I'm writing a custom text field type for my product SKUs.

If I have a SKU such as `ABC-DEF123G/5` (just an example), I want users to be able to search with or without the punctuation. In many cases, only part of the SKU is relevant, e.g. `ABC-DEF123` in my example.

So far, I've got my `schema.xml` looking like:

```
<fieldType name="sku" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            splitOnCaseChange="0"
            splitOnNumerics="0"
            stemEnglishPossessive="0"
            catenateAll="1"
        />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<!-- For use in Sunspot: -->
<dynamicField name="*_sku" stored="false" type="sku" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
```

This works well in that I can search for parts of a SKU, e.g. `DEF123` and get an appropriate result (thanks to the ngram filter). However, searching without punctuation delimiters doesn't return any matches: `ABC-DEF123G/5` is fine but `ABCDEF123G5` is not.

When I do analysis on my schema I see that searching for `ABCDEF123G5` has highlighted matches but when running an actual query there are no results returned.

I have restarted Solr and reindexed my documents. Many times.

Any pearls of wisdom on indexing SKUs or similar?

---

This editor ([aitchnyu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/604511/aitchnyu)) added this from Wikipedia:

> A stock-keeping unit or SKU  is a number or code used to identify each
>   unique product or item for sale in a store or other business.
>
> It is a unique identifier for each distinct product and service that
>   can be purchased. The usage of SKU is rooted in data management,
>   enabling the company to systematically track its inventory or product
>   availability, such as in warehouses and retail outlets. They are often
>   assigned and serialized at the merchant level. Each SKU is attached to
>   an item, variant, product line, bundle, service, fee, or attachment.
>   SKUs are often used to refer to different versions of the same
>   product. For example, a retail store carrying the game Guitar Hero 3
>   might have six SKUs, two for each of the three platforms—one with and
>   one without a guitar controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few days of periodically toying with this, I've finally settled on the following:

```
<fieldType name="sku" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This has been adapted from a default version of schema.xml supplied to be by a colleague.

**Edit:**

Relevancy was improved further by changing to edge n-grams and by shortening the n-gram minimum length.

`<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `copyField` with two different field types, e.g. `sku` and `sku_stripped`.

Define your `sku` field as you have above, then define `sku_stripped` with a `PatternReplaceFilterFactory`:

```
<fieldType name="sku_stripped" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
    <analyzer>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
             pattern="[^A-Za-z0-9]"
             replacement=""
             replace="all"/>
        <!-- same as above ... -->
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Then the copyField:

```
<fields>
    <!-- ... -->
    <field name="stripped_sku_field" type="sku_stripped" 
        indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</fields>
<copyField source="*_sku" dest="stripped_sku_field"/>
```